# Open database for ski resorts/stations

Tags: sports

I'm looking for an open database which contains information about Ski Resorts (called too as Ski Stations or Winter Stations), in Europe preferably.

Answer (score 2):

This EU document has a large amount of information on ski resorts in Europe, but it is in PDF format:

http://ec.europa.eu/consumers/ecc/docs/ski_resorts_eu_2010-2011_en.pdf

There is also a Wikipedia page for Ski Resorts in Europe. No idea on how comprehensive or accurate it is:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ski_areas_and_resorts_in_Europe

Comment: Thanks and +1 for the links, but this is not the answer because I'm looking for something more "queryable".