# Ski resort snow conditions / forecast API

Tags: api

I'm looking for an API for retrieving ski resort snow conditions and (hopefully) also condition forecasts.  At least for ski areas in North America, but global would be good too!

Specific data:

- Base Depth
- Season Total
- New snow

  - overnight
  - last 24 hours
  - week/other?
- Qualitative descriptor (ex: "packed powder")
- Acres/runs/lifts open
- Grooming report

A couple I've found:

- [OpenSnow API](http://opensnow.com/about/api) indicates "New OpenSnow API keys are no longer available, sorry of the inconvenience."
- [Weather2 Ski Resort Snow Report and Weather Forecast API](http://www.myweather2.com/developer/apis.aspx?uref=f8add9ec-fe95-4001-b822-df8680e49dce)

Related question: [Open database for ski resorts/stations](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6445/open-database-for-ski-resorts-stations)